# ¿Cómo superpongo la lista desplegable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me aparecen los datos detrás y deben ir adelante para seleccionar.
Al abrir el dialogo debe morstrar la lista con sus datos

```
  `<input id="colegio" name="colegio" class="form-control easyui-combobox" 
  url="json/barrios_get.php" style="width:236px;display: block;position: relative;"
  data-options="valueField:'nombre',textField:'nombre'">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="solicitar()">Solicitar</button>
`
este es el css

#dialogoPrueba{ border-color: #73b2d9; color: #0C7CC1; font-size: 14.5px;

display: block; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0;

}

#dialogoPrueba .container{ padding: 0 30px 30px; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; display: block;

}
```

Comment: En el css pones     z-index: 9999;

Comment: no siempre usar `9999` funcina, tambien podrias ver el  `z-index` del modal o cuadro de barrio para verificar que esta sucediendo y bajar el `z-index` en tiempo real con las herramientas de desarrollador que tiene el navegador.

Comment: @Yussef cuando pongo display: block al dialogo me lo deja en la pantalla principal pero ya lo muestra bien. Pero debería aparecer bien cuando pulso el botón para que abra el dialogo